# Combining workflow triggers (specifically schedule + pull_request) in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to figure out if I can set up one of my project's actions workflows to run no more than once per day, and only after at least one push to an active PR. The workflow is optional, but quite expensive to run so I'd rather not have it consuming actions resources for every push to a branch; running once per day is optimal. In order for this to work, the cron should be scheduled such that it can't run more than once even if multiple pushes occur.

From looking at the documentation, it seems that `schedule` and `pull_request` trigger independently. Because of that, I think I'd need to use something like workflow_dispatch in conjunction with a scheduled job (e.g. something like this: https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/github-actions/implementing-deferred-steps/) but the thing I'm not sure about is: my job requires accessing the PR information (since it's performing a comparison of the latest PR commit with its base commit, and then posting a comment on the PR thread). Will that even work in a deferred workflow?

Hoping to get some suggestions on how I can even approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) for such tasks. See [`gh pr`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr) for PR specific commands.

Comment: Do you happen to have any specific examples? From looking at the documentation, I see ways of inspecting the runs of a PR, inspect run statuses, and restarting runs. I don't see anything for scheduling new runs entirely (which, I think, would be needed for the problem).

Comment: You mentioned that you'd need `workflow_dispatch`, the corresponding command would be [`gh workflow`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run) i.e. `gh workflow run` to create new runs. If you could add a sample workflow what you want to do, that would be helpful to suggest something concrete. You've already figured most of it. The cron can be scheduled to run once per day. For PRs, you may use GitHub CLI commands to figure out if a workflow has already run or not. Or, you may simply choose to run it on merge only.